# What are the most profitable ingredients to plant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I've bought the house in Falkreath, where I have a greenhouse where I can plant some ingredients and harvest them.

Normally, I seed canis roots and swamp fungal pods. Every now and then I make paralysis potions with them and then sell/use the potions. I don't remember the exact value of this potion, but it's about 300 gold.

Are there any others ingredients that I can plant that are more profitable than those? I want to level up my alchemy faster.

I'm playing on Xbox.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [vanilla skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Useful_Potions), here is a list of the 10 most expensive potions you can make (with and without requiring giant's toes):

[image]

The only completely plantable potion in the list is the *Creep Cluster + Mora Tapinella + Scaly Pholiota* potion.